# How to Create Shared Weights Layer in Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm trying to set up a CNN in Keras, and I don't have much experience outside of simple NNs as far as the actual setup. I understand how the CNN is going to work on my data, but I need advice on how to set it up in Keras.

In my dataset, each datapoint is structured as follows. There are *n* columns, each of which is sensor data of people performing an action. There are 10 rows where each row is a single person's sensor data for that event. The label column is a score for how well they performed. Since each of their performances is related, each datapoint is a 10 by *n* matrix, and the label column for each data point is a 10 by 1 vector of scores.

Essentially, I want to set up my NN so that it treats:

```
Num|Sens0|Sens1|Sens2|Win
---|-----|-----|-----|---
A  |data |data |data | 0
B  |data |data |data | 0
C  |data |data |data | 0
D  |data |data |data | 0
E  |data |data |data | 0
F  |data |data |data | 0
G  |data |data |data | 0
H  |data |data |data | 1
I  |data |data |data | 0
J  |data |data |data | 0
```

the same as:

```
Num|Sens0|Sens1|Sens2|Win
---|-----|-----|-----|---
J  |data |data |data | 0
F  |data |data |data | 0
D  |data |data |data | 0
B  |data |data |data | 0
G  |data |data |data | 0
H  |data |data |data | 1
C  |data |data |data | 0
A  |data |data |data | 0
I  |data |data |data | 0
E  |data |data |data | 0
```

In my first layer (at the least), I want to set up convolutional neurons (I'm starting with 5, and moving on from there) so that each row shares weights amongst the observations, in such a way that the order I put the row in the datapoint doesn't matter (aside from it's correspondence with the label). Anyone know if this is possible? Otherwise I'll have to feed in each datapoint in all 10! orders, and I would prefer not to...

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In what way are the performances related? i.e. if the order does not matter, what would you lose from treating each row as a separate data point? Also, what is the goal? that is, what does the network predict?

Comment: @etov I was being purposely obtuse about this because I didn't want someone to jack my project, but I finished now. Basically, I have tracking data for basketball games, and I'm trying to use that tracking data to predict a couple things, specifically player movement, and who gets a rebound. I'd like to take in to account how people's movements are dependent on those around them. I found a way to totally order the players by position, but there's defo other approaches for how to order the players.

Comment: thanks for clarifying some more. If you're still interested in answers I'd suggest editing your question to be more concrete, with an example and even code if possible - this would help providing useful information to you, and increase the chances of helping others as well.

Comment: also, on a complete tangent: from my experience, the gain in telling people what you do and hearing their input almost always outweighs the risk of them "jacking" your project